# React.js - How to call a method after another method is fully executed

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have two simple functions. I am trying to call two functions in my "handleSearchClick" function when the button has been clicked.

I would like to run "this.props.getNewsDesc()" after "this.props.fetchNewsApiOrg(this.newsSourceName)" has been fully executed.

Here is the code:

```js
handleSearchClick = () => {
    this.props.fetchNewsApiOrg(this.newsSourceName);
    
    this.props.getNewsDesc();
  }
```

Could you please tell me the proper way to call a function after another function is fully executed?

Thank you.

Comment: Have `fetchNewsApiOrg` return a Promise, and `await` it or `.then` on it

Comment: What @CertainPerformance said. Also note that await can only be used within async functions.

Answer (score 9):

You can pass the method as a parameter and call the function from within the fetchNewsApiOrg().

```
handleSearchClick = () => {
    this.props.fetchNewsApiOrg(this.newsSourceName, this.props.getNewsDesc);
 }
...
fetchNewsApiOrg(newsSourceName,getNewDesc){
...
getNewDesc();
}
```

In this method you will have to bind getNewDesc like,
`this.getNewDesc = this.getNewDesc.bind(this)` in constructor.

Or you can go with promises.

```
handleSearchClick = () => {
    this.props.fetchNewsApiOrg(this.newsSourceName).then(()=>{
    this.props.getNewsDesc();
  })
```

Here the fetchNewsApiOrg should return a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Comment: Please accept it as answer if you find this as a solution for the stack overflow community and upvote if you find it useful